# How to pass an ARG to a Dockerfile in a docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a project `apkmirror-scraper-compose` with the following (simplified) structure:

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
└── tor
    └── Dockerfile
```

The `docker-compose.yml` is

```
version: '3'

services: 
  tor:
    build:
      context: ./tor
      args:
        password: ""
    ports:
      - "9050:9050"
      - "9051:9051"
```

The `Dockerfile` in the `tor` directory is:

```
FROM alpine:latest
EXPOSE 9050 9051
ARG password
RUN apk --update add tor
RUN echo "ControlPort 9051" >> /etc/tor/torrc
RUN echo "HashedControlPassword $(tor --quiet --hash-password $password)" >> /etc/tor/torrc
CMD ["tor"]
```

I'm trying to pass the argument `password`, which as the value `""` (an emtpy string), to the `Dockerfile`, so that it can hash it with Tor and add a `HashedControlPassword` line to the configuration file (cf. https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en).

However, if I `docker-compose build` followed by `docker-compose up`, the logs contain the following:

```
Creating network "apkmirrorscrapercompose_default" with the default driver
Starting apkmirrorscrapercompose_tor_1
Attaching to apkmirrorscrapercompose_tor_1
tor_1  | May 02 08:03:59.344 [notice] Tor v0.2.8.12 running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.22-stable, OpenSSL LibreSSL 2.4.4 and Zlib 1.2.8.
tor_1  | May 02 08:03:59.345 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
tor_1  | May 02 08:03:59.345 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
tor_1  | May 02 08:03:59.349 [warn] Linelist option 'HashedControlPassword' has no value. Skipping.
tor_1  | May 02 08:03:59.349 [warn] ControlPort is open, but no authentication method has been configured.  This means that any program on your computer can reconfigure your Tor.  That's bad!  You should upgrade your Tor controller as soon as possible.
```

In other words, the `password` argument is not getting 'picked up': Tor is saying it has "no value". Comparing with the example on https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args, however, I don't see what's wrong with either the `docker-compose.yml` or `Dockerfile`.

Can anyone spot what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem was with the `password` being an empty string. If I replace it by `"foo"`, the `docker-compose up` seems to work as expected.